# How do I activate an iPhone 3Gs without iTunes or WiFi?

Tags: ios, install, iphone

Is it possible to activate and use my iPhone 3Gs (A1303) without using iTunes?

I think it is important, not to connect it to a WiFi cause I don't want to update it in any way.

When I connect to a working WiFi and continue the activation process, it says:

> Your iPhone could not be activated because the activation server is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting your iPhone to iTunes to activate it, or try again in a couple of minutes.
>
> If this problem persists, contact Apple Support at apple.com/support

No matter, where and when I try that, it is the same message since months :)

When I connect it via iTunes, iTunes complains that there ought to be no SIM card in it.

So maybe it is better to find out to [How do I jailbreak an iphone 3gs without activating it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130832/how-do-i-jailbreak-an-iphone-3gs-without-activating-it)

Comment: It will ask you before updating anything so there is no worry to have about it.

Comment: OK so then the question is just if it is possible without iTunes?

Comment: I thought about jjailbraking it maybe later

Comment: You can upgrade it to any version as all versions of iOS6 can be jailbroken. iPhone 3GS cannot update to iOS7 if that's a concern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I jailbreak an iphone 3gs without activating it?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130832/how-do-i-jailbreak-an-iphone-3gs-without-activating-it)

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can activate your iPhone is using a sim-card. You don't have to connect to iTunes or WiFi.

It will show you alerts whether you want to upgrade or not, you can simply decline these.

Comment: I tried an icelandic sim card where I have no roaming here in germany, but it is still valid, and that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can create a activated custom firmware using Sn0wbreeze. Then restore the device with the custom firmware using Shift+Restore via iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can solve this problem by downgrading your iPhone. Download iOS 4.2 from redsn0w and then downgrade it by iTunes.